# How to change font to Times for just a paragraph in pdfLaTeX

Tags: fonts, times

For pdflatex, is it possible to change the font of just a paragraph of a document to times? I know that the `mathptmx` package can switch the font to something similar to Times New Roman. But, in some cases, I want to only use that font for just one paragraph, without influencing the other part in the document. Thanks!

Comment: One bad thing about LaTeX is that change fonts is ridiculous complex (for instance, in the anwer accepted you should that the font is the  cryptic keyword as "ptm"). The good thing about this complexity is that makes hard change the font in the middle of the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question was a bit ambiguous.  This MWE below will change the text (not math) font to times roman (`ptm`) for a paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont\lipsum[2]\par}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]